# Vuex: Observe logic in state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I don't know how to organize my Vuex store given  the following problem.

I have an array of buttons / actions, like 100s of them. They are are organized in the store like this:

```
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Button 1',
    doAction (store) {},
    mustShow (store) {
      return state.variable > 10 && state.variable2.counter < 12 && !state.variable3
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

I can easily display them in my view and link their action to the click event:

```
<button v-for"button in buttons" @click="button.doAction()"></button>
```

The problem is that each button can be shown or not based on arbitrary complex logic that it only knows, as you can see in the `mustShow` function. Each button has its distinctive logic.

I can easily make a getter that returns only the buttons whose `mustShow` function returns true to have only the actions that must be shown in a specific state of the store:

```
availableActions (state) {
    return state.buttons.filter(s => s.mustShow())
}
```

This works the first time, but the problem is that of course this getter is not reactive since it's not bound to state variables but to the result of a function that is not reactive.

How would you organize the code to make this work? Of course one could put all the display logic for all the buttons into a single getter. But what if I want the name of the button to be dynamic as well (as the result of a function that computes its value based on arbitrary variables in the state)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going the wrong way here: as a thumb rule you shouldn't have complex objects, like function definitions, defining your store state. A way of thinking about the store state is that should be something that you should be able to encode in JSON, give it to a friend, and then your friend if parses it back and use it in the same program should get the same result, so clearly a function inside the state won't fit this.

My suggestion would be to do something like:

```
const state = {
  buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Button 1',
    id: 1
  },
  ...
  ]
}
...
const actions = {
  doAction ({commit}, {btnId}) {
   // now you perform the action you want to do
   ...
   // finally if you want to change the state of your store you
   // should commit a mutation, *do not change the state here!*
   // let the mutation do their job
   // here you put all the things the mutation may need to perform 
   // the change of the state
   const payload = { btnId }   
   commit(changeSomethingInState, { payload })   
  }
}

const mutations = {
  changeSomethingInState (state, { payload }) {
    state.something = payload
}
...
```

This is in the store definition. Now in your view you do like:

```
<button v-for"button in buttons" @click="dispatch('doAction', { btnId: button.id })"/>
```

Comment: So, basically doAction (and mustShow) should be massive actions with a long switch in it?

Comment: It really depends of what are you going to do with every button click, if you think you need a huge switch you probably may consider to split further the vuex code into modules for each one of the parts of your applications.

Alternatively you can do something like `btnAtions[1] = () => { /* button 1 logic */}` and so on for each id

Comment: take a look at this [vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html), it may really help you.